# Barcode scanner automatic submit

Tags: excel, vba

I already have a barcode scanner VBA function, that recognizes the barcode number, but the problem I have is that I have to click enter every time, is there any way to do it automatically and store the count in a certain column? Currently it works if I enter the same value stored in column B, it will count the records in column C, but I want to avoid hitting enter every time

This is what I got so far

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
Dim TargetCell As Range
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2), TextBox1.Value) = 1 Then
    Set TargetCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Find(TextBox1.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)
    TargetCell.Value = TargetCell.Value + 1
Else
    MsgBox "Code not found"
End If
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: What would trigger the event?

Comment: Why not use `Workbook_SheetChange`?

Comment: The event will be trigger by a button, so pretty much click the button, it will open the user prompt and then just scan constantly

Comment: Can you configure the scanner to insert *[Enter]* after each scan? Most barcode scanners has this configurable setting.

Comment: Do you scan in a specific cell of your worksheet or in a textbox?

Comment: Into a textbox, so pretty much the scanner gets the code and will paste it where the focus is

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you have. For example, who presses the button? Or, does your scanner enter a return. I think the code below should work under any circumstances. Please try it.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Dim Qty As Long

    With TextBox1
        If Len(.Value) = 3 Then
            Set TargetCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2) _
                            .Find(.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If TargetCell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox """" & .Value & """ Code not found"
            Else
                With TargetCell.Offset(0, 1)
                    Qty = .Value + 1
                    .Value = Qty
                End With
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                TextBox1.Value = "Count = " & Qty
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If

            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Value)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I think you have a user form and in this form you have a text box called `TextBox1`. If so, the code should be in the user form's code module. If you have a text box in your worksheet paste the code to the code module of the sheet on which the text box resides.

Now, you need to adjust this line of code `If Len(.Value) = 3 Then` to determine when to process the data. This is because the *Change* event will occur whenever even a single character is entered. I tested with 3 characters. Change the number to a value equal to the length of the numbers you scan in. In theory that still leaves the CR hanging which your scanner might also send. If that causes a problem experiment with >= in place of the = in my code.

The code will add the scan to the existing quantity, just as you had it, and indicate the new total in the text box, in case you are interested. You might replace this with "OK". The code will select the text it enters. Therefore when you enter something else, such as a new scan, it will be over-written without extra clicks being required.